# SQL procedure loop on a key from JSON object

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to insert a JSON object into multiple tables

```
CREATE TABLE images
(
    id serial primary key ,
    image_url varchar(255),
    filename varchar(255)
);
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure example1(
    images_json json
)
AS
    $$
    DECLARE i json;
BEGIN
        RAISE NOTICE 'ITEM ID is %',images_json->>'item_id'; --will be used later on
    FOR i IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(images_json->>'images')
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO images (image_url, filename) VALUES (i->>'url', i->>'filename');
    end loop;
end;
    $$
    language plpgsql;
```

When I test it

```
call example1('{"item_id": 123,"images":[{ "url": "https://google.com","filename": "google.png"},
{ "url": "https://yahoo.com","filename":"yahoo.png"},
{"url": "https://www.bing.com","filename":"bing.png"}]}')
```

I get the following error

> ERROR: function json_array_elements(text) does not exist
>
> No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> Where: PL/pgSQL function example1(json) line 5 at FOR over SELECT rows

I want to insert each of the images array into `images` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate error is, that `->>` returns a `text` value, but `json_array_elements()` expects a `json` value. You need to use the `->` operator here:

```
FOR i IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(images_json -> 'images')
                                                        ^ here
```

But you don't need a LOOP for this (or PL/pgSQL to begin with):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure example1(images_json json)
AS
$$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'ITEM ID is %',images_json->>'item_id'; --will be used later on
  INSERT INTO images (image_url, filename) 
  SELECT i->>'url', i->>'filename'
  FROM json_array_elements(images_json -> 'images') as i;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: this works, can you add to the answer please, if for some reason I have to go with the for loop option

Comment: @porgrammer3124: See my first code example: it shows you how to do this with a (slow) LOOP.